# How to call the broker from Powershell?

Tags: content-delivery, powershell

I would like to query the broker database from a PowerShell script, but don't know where to start...

from the PS prompt* I manage to load the **Tridion.ContentDelivery.Interop.dll**

*This is done from a working and configured HttpUpload directory with the right DLLs, JARs and XMLs.

```
add-type -path .\tridion.contentdelivery.interop.dll
$q = new-object tridion.contentdelivery.dynamiccontent.query
```

and this results in errors...
[image]

So how to query content from the broker database with PS?

**2013-10-2 Update**: Some additional information after comments

In Java one would use something like:

```
import com.tridion.broker.querying.Query;
import com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.Criteria;
import com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.content.SchemaTitleCriteria;

Criteria criteria = new SchemaTitleCriteria(MY_SCHEMA);
Query query = new Query();
query.setCriteria(criteria);
try {
    String[] result = query.executeQuery();
} catch (StorageException e) { ... }
```

In PowerShell one would use something like this to call Oracle functionality:

```
add-type -path .\Oracle.DataAccess.dll
$conn = new-object oracle.dataaccess.client.oracleconnection("Data Source=...; User Id=...; Password=...");
$conn.open()
```

Now my challenge is not to do something else and write C# code or OData webservice but to find out:

- How to load the correct .NET CD DLL in PowerShell
- How to instantiate the right objects

like one would do in either Java or C#.

Comment: This will be tricky, as the Tridion CD core runs inside a JVM hosted by IIS... might be easier to add an odata webservice on top of your database

Comment: The direction you mention is then: my_query.aspx >> IIS / .NET >> JVM >> cd_core.jar.
and the route I try to do is: my_query.ps1 >> .NET >> JVM >> cd_core.jar.
My aim is to solve it via PS and .NET.

Comment: When calling the CD API from .NET, you should have a config and lib folder as subfolders of the current folder of your application. These folders should contain the cd-config files and jar-files, respectively.
I'm not saying this will work from PS though..

Comment: It's probably easier to use the OData webservice or write a custom exe in C# which you then call from PowerShell.

Comment: +1 to the approach and question. This would make for a great general-purpose delivery-side troubleshooting tool (no database queries). :-) RobStevenson-Leggett and Quirijn have good points--maybe start with the actual delivery-side code. The next question (C# to PowerShell) wouldn't be a Tridion question then.

Comment: Post the error(s) too since this might be configuration, license, etc problem rather than just syntax.

Comment: Presumably you aren't just doing this for fun, so perhaps it would help if you explained your use-case.

Comment: This will probably be seen as evil by some but here's a stackoverflow post that talks about how to query a database from Powershell: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423541/how-do-you-run-a-sql-server-query-from-powershell

Comment: Yep, definitely evil! But maybe useful sometimes, provided you NEVER change the database, only read from it. And of course, no guarantees it will work after an upgrade, service pack or whatever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually possible, but requires doing some hackwork. Use at own risk!

```
Write-Host 'Hello World! Lets hack a Tridion Jvm!'

# You'll need the assemblies listed below, plus xmogrt.dll
# in your executing directory

add-type -path '.\netrtsn.dll'
add-type -path '.\Tridion.ContentDelivery.Configuration.dll'
add-type -path '.\tridion.contentdelivery.dll'
add-type -path '.\tridion.contentdelivery.interop.dll'

# Let JuggerNet know we need the config and lib stuff
# This will only work if a) you're in TRIDION_HOME, 
# b) your config and lib dirs are below this executing dir.

[Tridion.ContentDelivery.Web.Jvm.ConfigurationHook]::Init()

# Corny way of tricking the process in loading a VM. Types injected 
# through depedency injection are not loaded.
# You can see that if you remove the $loader = part in the line below

$loader = [Codemesh.JuggerNET.JvmLoader]::GetJvmLoader('true','true')

# lets get all tcm ids of publication id 5
# below two lines need to be 1 line (formatting reasons)
$publicationCriteria = 
new-object Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.PublicationCriteria(5)

# below two lines need to be 1 line (formatting reasons)
$query = 
new-object Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Query($publicationCriteria)

$results = $query.ExecuteQuery()

$i=0
$cmf = new-object Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.ComponentMetaFactory(5)


do {
    Write-Host $results[$i]
    # Get the meta, just for fun
    Write-Host $cmf.getMeta($results[$i]).Title
    Write-Host $cmf.getMeta($results[$i]).Author
$i++
}
while ($i -lt $results.count)

Write-Host 'Cleaning up.'
# if $jvm is null the loader object will fail silently. 
# You should also be able to just close the process to unload the jvm.
$jvm = $loader.JvmIfCreated
$loader.UnloadCleanup($jvm)
```

Comment: Thanks! you'll need to run it from an x86 PowerShell since the DLLs are 32-bit, all lines work well, until the line $publicationCriteria = new-object Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.PublicationCriteria(5). It fails with the error message: New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor"... "The type initializer for 'Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.Criteria' thre an exception." ... + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException

Comment: It depends on whether your dlls are the 64 bit or the 32 bit ones. Powershell also comes in either variety, so match the one you load with the bit version of your Tridion DLLs.